# Returning a value with recursion in c++

Tags: c++, recursion

I had an interview and I could not answer this question.  You have an binary tree and you are putting all the nodes into an array using in_order and you return the value for the size of the array.  I was told that I could not use a helper function and add int i=0 for an array counter.

The recursive function heading I had to use was.

```
      In_order(Struct_Node * node, int *array){

      }
```

Because it was In_order I wrote.

```
      if(node){
      In_order(node->left, array);
```

//this line is where I am supposed to add the elements and return the value, 
but I do not understand how to do this.  This is my week point and I need to understand
the reasoning of how this code works more than what is the code.

```
      in_order(node->right,array); 
      }
```

I didn't actually write what I wrote in between the two In_order statements but what I wrote was wrong.

Comment: If you're going to return the array length, then your function definition should be `unsigned int in_order(Struct_Node * node, int * array) {`.

Comment: Take a look at the inorder traversal of a tree at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Sample_implementations). Replace printing with storing data in the array. Say `*array = node->data; array++;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guessing all the missing details I think you would do something like:

```
int In_order(Struct_Node * node, int *array){

   int count = 0;
   if (node->left) {
     count += In_order(node->left, array);
   }
   array[count++] = node->data; // whatever it is you're storing
   if (node->right) {
     count += In_order(node->right, array+count);
   }
   return count;
}
```

The key point is you pass an updated pointer to the RHS recursive call and your return value is `1 + LHS return + RHS return`

If you can't use an int as a counter (which is silly really because it's by far the clearest way of expressing it) you can do:

```
int In_order(Struct_Node * node, const int *array){
   int *tptr = array;

   if (node->left) {
     tptr += In_order(node->left, array);
   }
   *tptr++ = node->data; // whatever it is you're storing
   if (node->right) {
     tptr += In_order(node->right, tptr);
   }

   return tptr-array;
}
```

If you wanted to go "a little" crazy and avoid any locals other than the function arguments you could change the return type to be a pointer to the current working end of the array (which is in effect the size of the array also) and do:

```
int *In_order(const Struct_Node * const node, int * const result) {
  return !node ? result :
          In_order(node->right, &(*In_order(node->left, result) = node->value)+1);
}
```

Although to be quite honest that's terrible code (I'm not even 100% sure that it is well defined!) and I *really* hope they weren't looking for a solution like that!

Comment: I'm not sure the `count` variable is allowed, the rest is exactly what I would answer.

Answer (score 0):

In-order is a method of tree traversal; you travel the nodes in-order (hence the name) from left to right.

So for the insertion part, you would insert all the nodes to the left of the current node, **insert the current node**, and then insert all the nodes to the right.

After the `in_order(node->right,array)` call, you return your value (your problem description is unclear on exactly what you're supposed to be returning).

Answer (score 0):

For an inorder traversal:

1. Do an inorder traversal of the left subtree (if there is one).
2. Visit the current node.
3. Do an inorder traversal of the right subtree (if there is one).

In your case, "visit" means to add the current node to the list, and bump the counter.

As for putting the elements into an array, personally, i'd use a vector (and then convert/copy to an array at the end, if absolutely necessary).  You can create it in a "start" function that then calls the recursive one, or create it in the caller.  Either way, you pass a reference to it along in each call.  At the end, you have both an array of node values, and the count.  Otherwise you end up having to go through the tree once to count elements, and a second time to collect them.  (Or you could pass a reference or pointer to a pointer, so you can reallocate as needed, but that gets ugly.  Either way, i wouldn't trust the caller to know how big an array to give you -- it's your job to know/figure the size of your tree.  :P )